# Resizing a XAML control using the keyboard

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone

I was not able to find an answer to a simple question like this...
I'd like to resize a XAML control using keyboard, like I did in Windows Forms.
Example: in Windows Forms when I placed a TextBox in a form, I could resize it using [SHIFT]+[LeftArrow] or [SHIFT]+[RightArrow].
In this way I was able to resize that TextBox with a high degree of precision, without using the mouse.
If I do the same using XAML, the TextBox is being MOVED, not RESIZED.
I tried many keyboards combinations, but I was not able to find the equivalent of [SHIFT]+[LeftArrow] or [SHIFT]+[RightArrow] for XAML controls.

Do you know if such a shortcut exists?

Sorry if it seems a dumb question, but I'm missing this feature.

Comment: What's the version of your VS?

Comment: Whilst I understand your requirement, I can't help but feel that one of the benefits of using WPF over Winforms is the fact that you lay out controls using the dynamic containers and don't size everything manually

Comment: @Kulasangar: added VS2013 tag

Comment: @GaryWright I'm aware I have a lot to learn about WPF, but still I have no idea about precisely position controls except for manually setting Width in XAML or using the control properties...
Phones screens are small I have so many controls to position that every pixel saved can help me in this case.

Comment: If you post some sample xaml in your question of one of your complex layouts, perhaps I could take a look?

Comment: Uh, it's just a draft, but you can easily imagine a Windows Phone PanoramaItem filled with about 30 textboxes, 30 labels, several comboboxes, a webbrowser, a wrappanel with hubtiles and various images...
Your phrase: "one of the benefits of using WPF over Winforms is the fact that you lay out controls using the dynamic containers and don't size everything manually" is very interesting to me, so I'm trying to understand what you mean by reading some documentation about Editing XAML. Some good pointers about "lay out controls using the dynamic containers" will be helpful to me.

Comment: Take a look at this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479869.aspx as it shows examples of some different layout panels. If you do manage to achieve the layout you want with something like a `GridPanel` you will be able to run your application on any screen size and it will just expand or contract to fit the available space.

Comment: Gary, thanks for pointing that article: a good summary of WPF features. It is not exactly the answer to my question, but it helps me understanding more deeply some of the "philosophy" behind WPF design.

Comment: OK, I think I understood: less canvas, avoid as much as possible explicit control positioning, try to use panels, like WrapPanel, StackPanel, DockPanel and so on. @GaryWright thanks againg for pointing to the right direction a old WinForms (and formerly a VB 1,2...6 user). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer to my question, but I found very useful using Ctrl+MouseWheel: is a fast method to zoom the design part so that using the mouse becomes useful again when you REALLY need to be precise in resizing controls (like in a canvas container).

Make them big and resizing using mouse is easy and precise to the degree you wish (6400% is enough for everything, I think :-) )

Hit Ctrl+0 to go back to "Fit all" selection